# Web Audio API: controlling biquad filter nodes cutoff frequency

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

how is it possible to control the cutoff frequency of a filter node using an adsr envelope with the web audio api

I would expect following would work:

```
var filter = AudioContext.createBiquadFilter();       
filter.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(1000, 0.5);
```

but this immediately sets the value of the cutoff frequency after a 500ms delay without any form of transition.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that this is the first event sent to the filter. Looking at th MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) We can see the following text: `The linearRampToValueAtTime() method of the AudioParam Interface schedules a gradual linear change in the value of the AudioParam. The change starts at the time specified for the previous event, follows a linear ramp to the new value given in the value parameter, and reaches the new value at the time given in the endTime parameter.` I suspect you have no value until t = 0.5s

Comment: Yes.  Do a `filter.frequency.setValueAtTime(350, context.currentTime)` to set up the initial event.  Then `linearRampToValue(1000, 0.5 + context.currentTime)` will actually ramp.

Comment: You guys should add this as an answer rather than comments. I'll let you duke it out who should get the credit though. :) @RaymondToy